# Jersey client API WebResource accept() not setting MIME header correctly?

Tags: java, jersey

```
public static WebResource createWebResource()
{
    final ClientConfig  cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
    final Client        c = Client.create(cc);
    final WebResource   wr = c.resource("http://localhost:19801/wtg_inventory_war/wtg/rest")
                                  .path(inv);
    return wr;
}

public void tester()
{
final WebResource  wr = JaxrsClientUtil.createWebResource()
                                 .path("wtg-service");

    wr.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

String   response = wr.path("get-services")
                          .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                          .get(String.class);
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Server side:

```
@Path("get-services")
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response handleFindInventoryServices(
@Context WtgSpringContainer     ioc  // Spring config for service operations
)
{
    System.out.println("Got a service listing request...");
    LOGGER.info("Got a service listing request");

    Get the app specific data formatted in JAXB XML or JSON...

    .
    .
    .


    return Response.ok(msg).build();
}
```

Regardless of what the client side sets for acceptable media type, JSON comes back?  Using curl with -HAccept:application/json or application/xml works fine.  I'd like to test my server with both without changing the server side.

Any pointers as to why I cannot force the server to XML as my preferred MIME type?

Comment: Running into this as well trying to use the Jersey Client API to communicate with a CouchDB install -- text/plain is always sent regardless of what I set with accepts() so CouchDB always responds with text/plain and none of the POJO Mapping stuff ends up firing on the Jersey Client side because it never sees "application/json" -- I actually trued to FORCE the header via a ClientFilter, but it turns out those header Maps are immutable and just throw an exception when accessed for a write. Let me know if you find an answer to this.

Answer (score 3):

David, I figured it out. You did the same thing I did...

[WebResource.accept(..)](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#accept%28javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType...%29) is a static method and is actually returning a [WebResource.Builder](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.Builder.html) instance to you that we were both ignoring, with the correct accept param set on.

Once I changed my code from:

```java
WebResource res = c.resource("http://localhost:5984/");
res.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
System.out.println(res.get(String.class));
```

to:

```java
WebResource res = c.resource("http://localhost:5984/");
Builder builder = res.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
System.out.println(builder.get(String.class));
```

Everything started working, the correct 'Accept' headers got sent to the server.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did run in the same issue as you guys.

It works fine with using the accept header property.

An other interessting approach I figured out is to set the content type with the response builder as following:

```
     return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(dto).type(request.getContentType()).build();
```

If you do that you can use both the **accept** and the **content-type** property.