# Resteasy - GET Method - Passing XML

Tags: xml, get, jaxb, resteasy

I am trying to implement GET method in Resteasy. I couldn't use QueryParam because there are many search parameters including a complex type. So I thought of using XML. In the code below, both request and response are JAXB classes generated from schema. My question is how the client can pass the request xml?

```
@GET
@Path("search")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public SearchResponse searchTasks(SearchRequest searchReq)
{
```

Here's a sample client I created with Jersey. When I make a call, I am getting "415 Unsupported Media Type". Am I passing the XML right? Is it possible to send XML parameter to GET method?

```
    webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

    webResource.entity(req,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

    SearchResponse return1 = webResource.get(SearchResponse.class);
```

I am deploying this in Tomcat.

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Your question was already answered in [Jersey client API WebResource accept() not setting MIME header correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7435940/267197).

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because you are not setting the `Content-Type` header when you are making the request. Make sure it is set to `Content-Type: application/xml`.

On a side note, GET requests usually don't have a request body, although it is possible. I [suggest against including one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/978094/965648), and using a POST method instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But doesn't the following set the content type? - webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

Comment: **Arav** is right: he made an attempt to set the accepted content type, but did it not in a right way: `webResource.accept()` is actually returning a `Builder` which should be further used.