# How to send the https put request to a particular host having json content in its body using java?

Tags: java, https

I want to the send the https put request to a particular host with the json content in the request body using java. I don't know much about java. Please help!.

Comment: You need to search for "java rest clients" like jersey client

Comment: You could refer this stackoverflow thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644556/how-to-send-and-receive-a-put-request-containing-json-with-jersey